# Prove that $- \Delta(\eta^2 |\nabla u|^2) \le C |\nabla u|^2$ for $u$ harmonic.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, harmonic-functions

Let $B_1 = B(0, 1) \subset \mathbb R^n$, $\eta \in C^\infty_0(B_1)$ such that $\eta = 1$ on $B_{1/2}$ and let $u \in C^2(\overline{B_1})$ be a harmonic function. I want to show that
$$- \Delta(\eta^2 |\nabla u|^2) \le C |\nabla u|^2$$
for $C > 0$, where $|\nabla u|^2 = \sum_i (\partial_i u)^2$. We have
\begin{align}
- \Delta(\eta^2 |\nabla u|^2) &= - \Delta \eta^2 |\nabla u|^2 - \eta^2 \Delta |\nabla u|^2 - 2 \nabla \eta^2 \cdot \nabla|\nabla u|^2
\end{align}
where $2 \nabla \eta^2 \cdot \nabla|\nabla u|^2$ is the dot product in $\mathbb R^n$. We easily find that
$$\Delta |\nabla u|^2 = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n (\partial_{ij} u )^2 \ge 0,$$
so that, in addition of the fact that $\eta \in C_0^\infty(B_1)$, we get
$$- \Delta(\eta^2 |\nabla u|^2) \le C |\nabla u|^2 - 2 \nabla \eta^2 \cdot \nabla|\nabla u|^2.$$
I tried a lot of things to bound $- 2 \nabla \eta^2 \cdot \nabla|\nabla u|^2$ by a constant times $|\nabla u|^2$ but I am not able to get rid of the $\nabla$ before the absolute value in $\nabla|\nabla u|^2$.. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: I thought you need to assume $u \in C^3$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Any harmonic function is real analytic anyway by elliptic regularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that you do not throw away
$$- \eta^2 \Delta |\nabla u|^2= -\eta^2  \sum_{i,j} (u_{ij})^2$$

Note

$$\nabla \eta^2 \cdot \nabla|\nabla u|^2 = 2\eta \nabla \eta \cdot \nabla|\nabla u|^2  \le 2|\eta| | \nabla \eta|\ |\nabla|\nabla u|^2 |
$$
and
\begin{align}
|\nabla|\nabla u|^2 |^2 &= \sum_i (\partial_i \langle \nabla u, \nabla u\rangle)^2 \\
&= 4\sum_i (\langle \nabla u, \nabla u_i\rangle)^2 \\
&\le 4 |\nabla u|^2 \sum_i |\nabla u_i|^2 \\
&= 4|\nabla u|^2 \sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2 \\
\Rightarrow |\nabla |\nabla u|^2| &\le 2 |\nabla u| \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2}
\end{align}
So we have (using $ab\le \frac{1}{2\epsilon} a^2 + \frac{\epsilon}{2} b^2)$)

\begin{align}
-2\nabla \eta^2 \cdot \nabla|\nabla u|^2 & \le 4 |\eta| |\nabla \eta| |\nabla u | \sqrt{\sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2} \\
&= 4\left(  |\eta|\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2} \right)\bigg( |\nabla \eta| |\nabla u | \bigg) \\
&\le 4 \left( \frac{1}{4} \eta^2 \sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2 +  |\nabla \eta|^2 |\nabla u |^2  \right) \\
&=   \eta^2 \sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2 + 4|\nabla \eta|^2 |\nabla u |^2 . 
\end{align}

So we have
$$ - \Delta(\eta^2 |\nabla u|^2)\le  (- \Delta \eta^2 +4 |\nabla \eta|^2 )|\nabla u|^2\le C|\nabla u|^2$$

Comment: I do not really understand. After your calculations, you get 
$$-\Delta(\eta^2 |\nabla u|^2) \le -\Delta \eta^2 |\nabla u|^2 + 4|\nabla \eta|^2 |\nabla u|^2 + \eta^2\sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2,$$
and afterward you bound this by $ -\Delta \eta^2 |\nabla u|^2 + 4|\nabla \eta|^2 |\nabla u|^2 $ but where did go the term 
$$ \eta^2\sum_{i,j} u_{ij}^2~~ ? $$

Comment: where's the term $ - \eta^2 \Delta |\nabla u|^2 $? @Falcon Do not throw away this term.

Comment: Ahhhh yeah it cancels with the term we had before! That was why I was struggling so much. Thank you very much!